# Microsoft Excel Percentage Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get a formula to show a value of "<1%" (where I currently show "-1%"). I'm trying to show when less than 1 percent of an annual budget has been utilized. This is what my formula looks like:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(IF(C$19=0%,0%,IF(C$19<0.99%,-1%,C$19)),2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(C$19=0%,0%,IF(C$19<0.99%,"<1%",ROUNDDOWN(C$19,2)))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. And thanks also for the edit suggestions in my question. I see where what I originally typed could be somewhat confusing or misleading. Thank You